# How to find bug in utility-type application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, view, crash

I have written a utility type app that works great on simulator but very often crashes on real device (iPad). The crash occurs while coming back to MainView from FlipsideView. Either button doesn't react or it closes app (crash). I have duplicated everything about FlipsideView (controller, xib), changed name to FlipsideHView and modified it to support landscape orientation. This way I got 2 separate views to load depending on the orientation it was started from.

How can I find out what's the problem? Once it happens 10x in a row, other time it's hard to cause this bug.

Like I said, app works on Simulator and I don't have Development Device. Console is clean.

What should I look for?

Comment: Check if application consumes too much memory?..

Comment: @Vladimir "All allocations" position in Instruments doesn't extend 10 MB, usually around 5. Memory leaks are minor.

Comment: it was just a guess - memory is one of the 1st things to look at... try to ask clients to provide crash reports from their device may be?

Comment: @Vladimir Late reply.. the app doesn't show any error, just freezes or closes itself. The app is already in AppStore, approved by Apple and there are no crashes reported. But when I test it on a borrowed iPad it crashes a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was memory management.

Found it using "toggle memory warning" on simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't that helpful but my advice is get a development device.

If it works all the time on the simulator it doesn't matter what solution we suggest, you can't test it to see if it's the problem or not so you can't fix it.

The first step in fixing a bug is to reproduce it. If you can't reproduce it, how do you know you've fixed it?

Sorry this answer's not more helpful!

Comment: I don't think there's a chance to get dev device anytime soon :( That's why this post... Hoping that someone had such problem in past or can give any ideas where to look. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: Vladimir is probably on the right track with memory but my point is how will you fix it if you can't test it!